# How to convert string to UTF-8 string representation?

Tags: c#, string, encode, representation

As i mentioned in the title. For example:

If the input looks like:

```
FW: Błąd zakładania FA/PA
```

I would like to receive:

```
=?utf-8?B?Rlc6IELFgsSFZCB6YWvFgmFkYW5pYSBGQS9QQQ==?=
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this *specific case* Base64 encoded text exists in this *MIME encoded* string after the `B?`upto the next `?`

```
string mimed = "=?utf-8?B?Rlc6IELFgsSFZCB6YWvFgmFkYW5pYSBGQS9QQQ==?=";

mimed = mimed.Substring(10, mimed.IndexOf("?", 10) - 10);

string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(mimed));
```

The reverse:

```
result = string.Format("=?utf-8?B?{0}?=", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"FW: Błąd zakładania FA/PA")));
```

Comment: Thats something that I am looking for. But is it possible to do in reversed direction?

Comment: I want to get mimed from result